# how to make text in a button align right using style in material component?

Tags: android, android-xml, material-components-android, material-components

[image]

I am using material component, and I have a button in an Alert Dialog like the image above using the style below

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogMaterialTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogMaterialTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Negative</item>
</style>

<style name="Alert.Button.Negative" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/color_0054BB</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_0054BB</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">8dp</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorAccent_main</item>
</style>
```

as you can see the "cancel" text is in the center of the button. but now I need to make that "cancel" text align right . how to make something like that ?

I use the code below to how the alert dialog

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(mContext)
     .setTitle("this is title")
     .setMessage("this is message")
     .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->

     }
     .setNegativeButton("No") { d, _ ->
         d.dismiss()
     }
     .show()
```

Comment: Did you tried         android:textAlignment="textEnd"

Comment: Have you tried using ```android:gravity="right|center_vertical" ``` as another property for the cancel button?